# Bash - disappearing values while concatenating strings

Tags: string, bash, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to insert into the file values which I get from another file (xml) and I want them to be in one row. I checked variables - separately they are but once I try to concatenate them somehow, something goes wrong and I get only parts of the prior strings.

My code looks as it follows:

```
echo $usd
echo $gbp
all=$usd$space$gbp
echo $all
```

The output looks like this:

```
3,6525
5,5407
 5,5407
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong? Or what can I do to restore my data?

Comment: The concatenation looks okay. It must be a problem with your data. You should show more code.

Comment: Your data contains carriage return characters `\r` -- verify with `echo "$usd" | od -c` -- run `dos2unix` on your input files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a CR in your variable. I can reproduce your case with the vars

```
usd="3,6525^M"
gbp="5,5407^M"
space=" "
```

(I entered ^M in vi with CTRL-V CTRL-M, it is the \r character)
When you do not want to clean the xml, usd and gbp, you can use

```
all=${usd%$'\r'}${space}${gbp%$'\r'}
```

Comment: Or run dos2unix on the source file to remove the bad characters. That fixed it for my case.